# Angular JS Use modal in ng-repeat list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am displaying a list using AngularJS's ng-repeat... Below is the template per list item; It all works except for the {{...}} that are used inside bootstraps modal. It 'almost' works the way it should but any {{..}} called in the modal calls data from the FIRST list item not the list item that was clicked...

```
                              <ul>
                                <li ng-repeat="faIcon in faIcons | filter:search" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 anIcon">

                                  <a data-toggle="modal" href='#icon-select'>
                                    <i class="fa fa-fw">{{faIcon.theIcon}}</i> <!-- THESE WORK -->
                                    {{faIcon.name}}
                                    <span class="muted">{{faIcon.code}}</span>

                                    <a href="#" class="btn-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" ng-click="remove($index)" data-original-title="Remove From List"> X </a>
                                  </a>





                                  <div class="modal fade" id="icon-select">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                                      <div class="modal-content">

                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                          <h4 class="modal-title">{{faIcon.name}}</h4> <!-- These will load the name of the first list itme only -->
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                          <h1><i class="fa fa-fw">{{faIcon.theIcon}}</i></h1>
                                        </div>


                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                        </div>
                                      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                                    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                                  </div><!-- /.modal -->

                                </li>
                              </ul>
```

HELP!

Below is the angular controller

```
              var faList = function ($scope){
                $scope.faIcons = [
                    {theIcon: "", name: "fa-adn", code: "[&#xf170;]"},
                    {theIcon: "", name: "fa-youtube", code: "[&#xf167;]"},
                    {theIcon: "", name: "fa-youtube-play", code: "[&#xf16a;]"},
                    {theIcon: "", name: "fa-youtube-square", code: "[&#xf166;]"}
                  ];


                $scope.add = function (){
                  $scope.faIcons.push({
                    theIcon: $scope.new_icon,
                    name: $scope.new_name,
                    code: $scope.new_code,
                  });
                    $scope.new_icon = "";
                    $scope.new_name = "";
                    $scope.new_code = "";
                };

                $scope.remove = function(index){
                  $scope.faIcons.splice(index,1);
                };
              };
```

Comment: Create a jsfiddle please.

Comment: Would it be out of line to ask why you have modals inside an ng-repeat?

Comment: Since using angularjs, i've never had the need to actually use the modal html, it comes built-in with angular ui bootstrap if you use the modal directive.

Comment: Kevin B - For every list item I want to be clickable to activate a modal with specific info regarding the item clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your created modals have the same id, so

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href='#icon-select'>
```

opens the first modal created. Consider moving your modals outside the loop.

Comment: Every list item needed it's own href-id to correspond with the modal. id="{{faIcon.iconSelect}}"....Each list item was assigned its own iconSelect ID in the controller... I used the iconSelect to name the modal and in the href that calls the modal